# How to define prop validation rule for an object of objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the props are an object of records, such as:

```
const pets = {
    "P001": { id: "P001", name: "Jim",  type: "Dog" },
    "P002": { id: "P002", name: "Jack", type: "Cat" },
    "P003": { id: "P003", name: "Jill", type: "Dog" },
};
```

How does one validate that is a "keyed" array of x shape?

**Failed Attempt One**

I would like to define the validation rules as such:

```
pets: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({
    id:   React.PropTypes.string,
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    type: React.PropTypes.string
}))
```

This of course fails, because it is looking for:

```
const pets = [
    { id: "P001", name: "Jim",  type: "Dog" },
    { id: "P002", name: "Jack", type: "Cat" },
    { id: "P003", name: "Jill", type: "Dog" }
];
```

**Failed Attempt Two**

```
pets: React.PropTypes.shape(React.PropTypes.shape({
    id:   React.PropTypes.string,
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    type: React.PropTypes.string
}))
```

This of course fails too, because it is looking for:

```
const pets = {
    { id: "P001", name: "Jim",  type: "Dog" }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a customArrayProp.

```
// You can also supply a custom validator to `arrayOf` and `objectOf`.
    // It should return an Error object if the validation fails. The validator
    // will be called for each key in the array or object. The first two
    // arguments of the validator are the array or object itself, and the
    // current item's key.
    customArrayProp: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(function(propValue, key, componentName, location, propFullName) {
      if (!/matchme/.test(propValue[key])) {
        return new Error(
          'Invalid prop `' + propFullName + '` supplied to' +
          ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
        );
      }
    })
```

see here. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: I was hoping for a more generic way to approach this - I guess I could create a generic function to pass in though

Comment: You just copied the docs, a more concrete answer is needed here.